# Mobile menu's jerky sliding animation

Tags: jquery, animation

When viewing [my page](http://goo.gl/M783K1) (login = "mmt" | pass = "mmt_nv2014") with viewport width below 1068px or on a mobile phone, the hamburger icon (top left) opens a menu sliding from the left via this code:

```
$( '#mobile_left_menu_icon' ).click(function() {
    if( $('#mobile_left_menu').css('left') == '-280px' ) { 
        $( "#mobile_left_menu" ).animate( { left: "0" }, open_delay, 'easeInOutExpo' ); 
        $( "#wrapper" ).animate({ left: "280px" }, open_delay, 'easeInOutExpo' );
        $( "#mobile_top_menu" ).animate({ left: "280px" }, open_delay, 'easeInOutExpo' );
        $( 'body' ).addClass( 'overflow_hidden' );
    }
    else { 
        $( "#mobile_left_menu" ).animate({ left: "-280px" }, close_delay, 'easeInOutExpo' );
        $( "#wrapper" ).animate({ left: "0" }, close_delay, 'easeInOutExpo' );  
        $( "#mobile_top_menu" ).animate({ left: "0" }, close_delay, 'easeInOutExpo' );  
        $( 'body' ).removeClass( 'overflow_hidden' );
    }
});
```

For some reason though, the animation feels quite jerky on a smartphone compared to any other website with similar sliding menu. Why is that?

Comment: Rather than using JS to animate your menu, try using CSS transitions. You can program in a JS fallback but you can hardware accelerate CSS transitions and make them quite smooth. To hardware accelerate, try animating the `transform` property rather than `left`. There are other tricks you can use as well but that's my suggestion.

Comment: Thanks but it's not just the menu I have to move, the #wrapper element containing the whole page must also move at the same time. Can this be done the way you describe?

Comment: Yes you can. I would suggest adding and removing a class from the `html` element that describes the state of your menu and wrapper elements. Anytime you find yourself animating a `left` or `top` (or similar) property on a mobile device, think about changing to `transform`. If you set a `transform` or `opacity` for an element, that element is placed on its own layer for rendering and can be sent to the GPU rather than the CPU. This can lead to some really nice animations. Here's an article that will give a nice overview of this topic: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/html5/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
```

I would also recommend adding a set height to the menu as that usually helps with the flicker while transitioning.