# Why is my simple CSS transition animation jerky on smartphones?

Tags: css, user-interface, animation, mobile-website

After [being advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929040/mobile-menus-jerky-sliding-animation) to switch from jQuery animation to CSS animation in order to make my mobile menu animation smoother, I still find that the animation of the mobile menu opening on a smartphone is jerky and I don't know what to do to improve it.

JS:

```
$( '.header__menu_icon' ).click(function() {
  var allClasses = 'right_0 right_280 right_minus_280';
  $( '.mobile_menu, .wrap' ).removeClass( allClasses );
  if ( $('.wrap' ).css( 'right' ) == '0px' ) { 
    $( '.wrap' ).addClass( 'right_280' ); 
  }
  else { 
    $( '.wrap' ).addClass( 'right_0' ); 
  }
});
```

CSS:

```
.mobile_menu {
  width: 280px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -280px;
}
.right_0 {
  right: 0 !important;
}
.right_280 {
  right: 280px !important;
}
.right_minus_280 {
  right: -280px !important;
}
body,
.wrap,
.mobile_menu {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='header'>
    <div class='mobile_menu'>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

EDIT:
New code based on @GaijinJim's answer below.

JS:

```
$( '.header__menu_icon' ).toggle( function() {
  $( '.wrap' ).removeClass( 'mobile_menu_opening mobile_menu_closing' );
  $( '.wrap' ).addClass( 'mobile_menu_opening' ); 
}, function() {
  $( '.wrap' ).removeClass( 'mobile_menu_opening mobile_menu_closing' );
  $( '.wrap' ).addClass( 'mobile_menu_closing' ); 
});
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes mobile_menu_opening {
  0% { 
    transform: translateX(0px); 
  }
  100% { 
    transform: translateX(-280px); 
  }
}
@keyframes mobile_menu_closing {
  0% { 
    transform: translateX(-280px); 
  }
  100% { 
    transform: translateX(0px); 
  }
}
.mobile_menu_opening {
  animation-name: mobile_menu_opening;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
.mobile_menu_closing {
  animation-name: mobile_menu_closing;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Try using the specific property in the transition instead of all.

Comment: I recommend using CSS Transforms which you can read about [here](https://blog.alexmaccaw.com/css-transitions), it will have a tremendous performance impact on your mobile that I'm sure you will like.

Comment: @GaijinJim yes, writing a reply to your answer now

Comment: Thanks, if it worked, could you please accept it? Not just upvote it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds more like of a performance issue due to the fact that you're not using transforms.

Has mentioned in [A Tale of Animation Performance](https://css-tricks.com/tale-of-animation-performance/) by Chris Coyier

> It has become common generic advice that using translate() to move
>   elements has better performance than using top/right/bottom/left.
>
> [...]Paul talked to another Paul on the **Chrome Team**, Paul Lewis, who agreed
>   that it is "smarter to use translate() for design-y motion." But went
>   on to say that there is more to this than frame rate. With
>   translate(), you get sub-pixel animation which is a kind of blurring
>   between pixels that usually leads to smoother animation

You can also read this great article about [All you need to know about CSS Transitions](https://blog.alexmaccaw.com/css-transitions):

> **Hardware acceleration**
>   Transitioning certain properties, such as left
>   and margin causes the browser to recalculating styles every frame.
>   This is fairly expensive, and can lead to unnecessary re-paints,
>   especially if you have a lot of elements on the screen. This is
>   especially noticeable in less powerful devices, such as mobiles.
>
> This solution is to offload the rendering to the GPU using CSS
>   transformations. In simple terms, this turns the element into an image
>   during the transition, avoiding any style recalculations which greatly
>   increases performance.

So in your case I would change your whole classes that are a bit of a mess in all due respect to a simple animation like:

```
@keyframes buttonInOutAnimation{
    0%{transform:translateX(-280px);}
    50%{transform:translateX(280px);}
    100%{transform:translateX(-280px);}
}
```

Then you can assign this animation to your button class like so:

```
.YourClassToAnimate{
    animation: buttonInOutAnimation 1s ease-in-out 0s 1;
}
```

Then you can assign this class with jquery like you've been doing already.

One last thing:
In your case you need to add the fill-mode to freeze the animation state at the end of the animation.

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

`forwards` leaves the animation in the state of the last frame.
`backwards` leaves the animation at the start

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailed answer! There's an issue though: once the ".wrap" container finished to move 280px leftwards it immediately jumps back to its initial position. Why and how to prevent this?

Comment: Sorry about that, you need to add the fill-mode to freeze the animation state at the end of the animation. 

   `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;`

`forwards` leaves the animation in the state of the last frame

`backwards` leaves the animation at the start

Comment: Thanks @gaijinJim, works perfectly now! I accepted your answer.

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help. Those CSS Transitions articles are really worth reading!